# How to know the purpose of jar files?

Tags: jar

I am developing a project using **struts2**, **hibernate** with **eclipse IDE**. Here, i am having so many jar files such as

1. antlr-2.7.6.jar
2. aopalliance-1.0.jar
3. asm.jar
4. cglib-2.2.jar
5. classworlds-1.1.jar
6. commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
7. commons-chain-1.2.jar
8. commons-collections-3.2.jar
9. commons-digester-2.0.jar
10. commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar

and many more. But now, i want to know the purpose of these jar files. Is there any websites are available to know the purpose of all jar files?

Answer (score 0):

These jars are dependencies  to run a struts2 applications efficiently and fast. Since all the above jars are open source project and developed and maintained by various developers across the worlds. These jars are designed and developed to target some specific goals and and these are best suited for specialize section of requirement. These jars are developed using best possible algorithm. For example **commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar** is best suited for **file upload task**.

Therefore instead of wasting time in developing own classes & jars for a project why dont we use already developed best suited project as a jar. It reduces times and increases productivity. **So struts2 usage these jars in manner to achieve some goals and task and relatively accomplish the user requirements.**

For example struts2 usage **commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar** for its file-upload requirements. Modularizing and utilizing the existing resources is only the ultimate goal of **OOP** programing and doing this it can be achieved.

**Remember reinventing the wheel is of no use.**

Comment: thank you for your golden words. but now i doing this for my final year project. so i want to know each and everything about my project. and it is also need for my project document.

Comment: well i have also done my final project during my college day, so in your project you have to document struts2 framework not its dependencies. Struts2 framework itself is so detailed that it will cover your all project documentation. so try to explain struts2 framework,its architecture, work flow,interceptors, actions, plugins rather than concentrating on its dependencies.

Comment: my pleasure ,if this answer satisfies you accept it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Is there no way to know the purpose of jar file?

Comment: ofcorse there is always a full documentation regarding a project or jar files. If you really want to know about jars then google it, you will get all what you want to know. for example to know about 'commons-fileupload' refer this http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/index.html